# Is there a need for ie fixes

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

Is an ie.css file still needed? It still maintains a common place within many project structures. Also sending people to browse happy or an error page is definitely used in front end frameworks. But are users still using ie7/8/9? Or have people evolved their browsing habits.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Then why do people still use IE hacks?

Comment: `are users still using ie7/8/9?` - oh yes.

Comment: People still use IE hacks because: http://theie8countdown.com/

Comment: But should we still cater for the minority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on whether or not the code you write is IE compatible. You don't need to create an ie.css file generally. There's usually ways to write code such that it is compatible, with the exception of some CSS3 properties not supported by IE8 and below. It depends on personal preference or company policy whether or not to support IE8 and below though. It also depends on how new the CSS properties are.

Here's a useful site for reference, letting you know what is compatible with what browser and what version:
http://caniuse.com

Each browser has their own quirks too, so it's not just IE that may be the issue. You can take some measures, though not guaranteed, such as using something like Normalize.
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/